# How to change specific lines in a text file and enforce this change when writing output file

Tags: python, io, overwrite

I'm having an issue with implementing a change on specific files in a text file. I have looped over the lines and identified the ones starting with a specific character (N2).

I'm trying to wrap a paragraph so it only allows for 100 characters per line for the abstract of this output from an online source, numerous abstracts are contained in the file all starting with N2 prefixed to the string.

The information appears as separate lines in the text file, ForEoin.txt:

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->
TY  - JOUR 
ID  - 31513460
T1  - Systematic Review: Clinical Metabolomics to Forecast Outcomes in Liver Transplantation Surgery.
A1  - Attard, Joseph A
A1  - Dunn, Warwick B
A1  - Mergental, Hynek
A1  - Mirza, Darius F
A1  - Afford, Simon C
A1  - Perera, M Thamara P R
Y1  - 2019//
N2  - Liver transplantation is an effective intervention for end-stage liver disease, fulminant hepatic failure, and early hepatocellular carcinoma. Yet, there is marked patient-to-patient variation in liver transplantation outcomes. This calls for novel diagnostics to enable rational deployment of donor livers. Metabolomics is a postgenomic high-throughput systems biology approach to diagnostic innovation in clinical medicine. We report here an original systematic review of the metabolomic studies that have identified putative biomarkers in the context of liver transplantation. Eighteen studies met the inclusion criteria that involved sampling of blood (n = 4), dialysate fluid (n = 4), bile (n = 5), and liver tissue (n = 5). Metabolites of amino acid and nitrogen metabolism, anaerobic glycolysis, lipid breakdown products, and bile acid metabolism were significantly different in transplanted livers with and without graft dysfunction. However, criteria for defining the graft dysfunction varied across studies. This systematic review demonstrates that metabolomics can be deployed in identification of metabolic indicators of graft dysfunction with a view to implicated molecular mechanisms. We conclude the article with a horizon scanning of metabolomics technology in liver transplantation and its future prospects and challenges in research and clinical practice.
KW  - *Biomarkers
KW  - Genotype
```

So far I have iterated over the lines of the file and called upon the textwrap module to wrap this for me but I cant get my head around writing over the existing lines with this new wrapped lines in the output file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import textwrap

filename_org = 'ForEoin.txt'
filename_new = 'Eoin_Shortline_v2'


with open(filename_org, 'r') as rf:
    with open(filename_new, 'w') as wf:
        for line in rf:
            if line.startswith("N2"):
                wrapper = textwrap.TextWrapper(width=100)
                new_line = wrapper.fill(text=line)

                wf.write(new_line)
```

Comment: Why would it write over the existing lines? You are writing to the `wf` file handle, which keeps appending what you write to the output file. Is it outputting something wrong? Have you run the code? You should give an example of what it output if you did run it, and what didn't match your expectations. One thing: I think you will need to write a newline `"\n"` after `wf.write(new_line)` or all your text will run together.

Comment: @Sam the output is as expected but I want to retain all the other lines I have not applied this wrap function is all. So the output is just returning the wrapped abstract paragraph which occurs many times in the original text file but none of the other original line [TY, ID etc.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you just need an `else` statement, to write the line un-altered if it doesn't start with N2?

```
with open(filename_org, 'r') as rf:
    with open(filename_new, 'w') as wf:
        for line in rf:
            if line.startswith("N2"):
                wrapper = textwrap.TextWrapper(width=100)
                new_line = wrapper.fill(text=line)
                wf.write(new_line)
            else:
                wf.write(line)
```

Comment: works perfectly, thanks very much. I'm very much a rookie and I'm stumbling when it comes to applying a lot of the logical stuff along with the knowledge of python [in built functions, methods etc.].

Answer (score 0):

```
import textwrap

filename_org = 'ForEoin.txt'
filename_new = 'Eoin_Shortline_v2'


with open(filename_org, 'r') as rf:
    with open(filename_new, 'w') as wf:
        for line in rf:
            if line.startswith("N2"):
                wrapper = textwrap.TextWrapper(width=100)
                new_line = wrapper.fill(text=line)
                wf.write(new_line)
            else:
                wf.write(line)
```

If the line starts with "N2" do the wrapper and then write it to the file in the else part also you have to right it to the file.